# Perl : How to obtain epoch time

Tags: perl

I need a quick way to convert date **"Tue Jul 02 17:50:55 MDT 2024"** into epoch time.

Effectively, I need the shell equivalent of `date -d "Tue Jul 02 17:50:55 MDT 2024" +%s`

I currently use the following in perl but it requires a lot of conversion. Hoping to find a simpler and more elegant solution.

```
$current_epoch = timelocal($seconds, $minute, $hour, $day_of_month, $month_num, $year)
```

I currently use Perl 5.8 ; I dont believe it has "Time::Piece"
I am only interested in solutions that do not require downloading another library

Answer (score 0):

The [Date::Parse](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Date::Parse) module can turn datetime stamps into epoch times. In general, if you have something you need to do, search the [Comprehensive Perl Archive Network](http://www.metacpan.org) for a module to handle it. Searching Stackoverflow is another good way to get answers to common questions.